# How to use a button to clear multiple cells in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, cells

How can I clear many cells at once.

If I want to clear A1, A10, B10, B20 by just using one button or link. 
Only clearing those 4 specific cells in my example.

I want to have a button that will clear all those cells when I need to. Not just once.

Comment: You could lengthen your question by including details of what you have researched and attempted so far. Maybe reading **[ask]** would be beneficial to improving your question.

Comment: Just an FYI, are you talking about only clearing those 4 specific cells in your example?  or do you mean from A1 to A10 and B10 to B20?  That isn't very clear, but I will answer it in both ways just in case.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that I am talking about clearing only those 4. I have also searched on superuser previously but didn't find any answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign this macro:

```
Sub dural()
   Range("A1,A10,B10,B20").Clear
End Sub
```

to your button.

Comment: sub-dural - ha!

Comment: @Raystafarian  Anything for a smile!

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Click to select individual cells to delete.  So if you click on A1, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ Click A10, B10, and B20 it will select those 4 cells and you can just hit delete on your keyboard.

If you use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ Click, you would want to click A1, Shift + Click A10 to select everything between those 2.  After that if you want to select another group, use CTRL + click to select B10, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ Click B20 and it will select everything between B10-B20 and still have A1-A10 highlighted.

Hope that makes sense, but <kbd>Shift</kbd>and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + clicking is very useful for selecting multiple fields/cells/etc.

Comment: I want to have a button that will clear all those cells when I need to. Not just once.

Comment: @Imageree that was not very clear in the question.

Comment: Yes I know sorry - I will correct that.